# Creating depressionless DEMs with rgrass7

Tags: r, rgrass7, sink

I'm working with the `rgrass7` package to use `GRASS 7.6.0` functions within R. What I'm trying to do is the following: Import a raster DEM with a custom CRS, fill the sinks and export the depressionless raster - all via RStudio.
Some sample data can be found at: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT

I have never worked with GRASS before so I might just be missing a single command, but all my outputs are just empty rasters. Maybe this is a projection problem?

My code so far is this:

```
library(rgrass7)
initGRASS(gisBase = "/usr/.../grass76/", 
          home = tempdir(), 
          mapset = "PERMANENT", 
          override = TRUE)

# modify current mapset with custom projection
execGRASS("g.proj", flags = "c", proj4 = "+proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=50 +lat_0=37 +lon_0=87 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
execGRASS("g.mapset", flags = "c", mapset = "new_mapset")

# load DEM
execGRASS("r.in.gdal", input = "/path/to/.tif", output = "GRASS_raster", flags = c("overwrite"))

# set region (following the comment of @dmci = fixes the issue)
execGRASS("g.region", raster = raster("/path/to/.tif"))

# fill sinks
execGRASS("r.fill.dir", input = "GRASS_raster", output = "GRASS_filled_DEM", direction = "flow_test") # fill sinks
# export depressionless DEM
execGRASS("r.out.gdal", input = "GRASS_filled_DEM", output = "path/to/filled_DEM.tif")) # export filled DEM
```

This process does create a `GRASS_raster` and a `filled_DEM.tif` but they are just empty 1x1 raster files when I load them into RStudio.

I have tried to do this process with the GUI of GRASS. The imported DEM can be seen in the map display window, but the results of `r.fill.dir` are only empty rasters like this:

[image]

Comment: are you sure that you have set `g.region rast=yourinputraster` before running the process?

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my code above with your solution. I still need to check the output data for accuracy, but at least I'm not getting empty raster frames. Thank a lot! Maybe you put your solution in a real answer so I can mark my question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, after importing your raster into your mapset, it is necessary to run `g.region rast=youinputraster` or as follows based on your script:

```
# set region (following the comment of @dmci = fixes the issue)
execGRASS("g.region", raster = raster("/path/to/youinputraster.tif"))
```

More details and options relating to `g.region` can be found on the [GRASS documentation page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/g.region.html)