# Calculating sink volume in R via rgrass7

Tags: r, contour, tin, volume, rgrass7

I want to calculate the volume of sinks in a DEM raster in R, since I have to automatize the workflow later. Following the results of my previous question ([Creating depressionless DEMs with rgrass7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/344948/145570)) I have my rasters clipped to the extent of the sinks. I did that by doing:

```
sinks <- regular_raster.tif - depressionless_DEM.tif
sinks[sinks == 0] <- NA
```

Now I'm looking for a way to calculate the volume of all the sinks in this raster. In ArcGIS or QGIS I would region group the raster, then calculate a contour file and a TIN for every sink and calculate its volume.
Within GRASS, all I find are ways to calculate a DEM from a contour file (like the `v.surf` and `r.surf` packages), but not the other way around. What am I missing? Or is the workflow in GRASS different?